# Google Maps API + Wax.g + IE = Tiny Tiles

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, mapbox

I'm using [wax.g](http://www.mapbox.com/wax/connector-g.html) to display custom tiles on a Google Map. This works fine in every browser I've tested, except IE. In other browsers, the tiles are rendered correctly, but in IE, the tiles a rendering as a smaller version of their true selves. The issue is best explained in the following screenshots:

What they should look like: http://cl.ly/image/2E0U2b0c0f0W

What they look like in IE: http://cl.ly/image/2F3B353q0G0c

This issue doesn't happen all the time, and if I pan or zoom, sometimes I get the correctly sized tiles, and sometimes I don't. Not sure if this is a Wax issue or an issue with how the Google Maps API renders custom `overlayMapTypes`. Has anyone else experienced this issue? Any insight is much appreciated...

(cross-posted from [MapBox GitHub issue](https://github.com/mapbox/wax/issues/280) - no answers there yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that my images were inheriting a style height and width of auto, and Wax.g's `getTile` method method creates an `Image` using `new Image(256, 256)`, which writes to height and width attributes of the `img` itself (`img` attributes, not inline style). The inline styles took priority over the attributes, so the `img` was being sized using `auto`. I fixed this by ensuring the img had a height and width of 256 using inline styling.

Wax.g code:

```
// Get a tile element from a coordinate, zoom level, and an ownerDocument.
wax.g.connector.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
    var key = zoom + '/' + coord.x + '/' + coord.y;
    if (!this.cache[key]) {
        var img = this.cache[key] = new Image(256, 256);
        this.cache[key].src = this.getTileUrl(coord, zoom);
        this.cache[key].setAttribute('gTileKey', key);
        this.cache[key].onerror = function() { img.style.display = 'none'; };
    }
    return this.cache[key];
};
```

My modified code:

```
// Get a tile element from a coordinate, zoom level, and an ownerDocument.
wax.g.connector.prototype.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument) {
    var key = zoom + '/' + coord.x + '/' + coord.y;
    if (!this.cache[key]) {
        var img = this.cache[key] = new Image(256, 256);
        img.style.height = '256px';  // added this line
        img.style.width = '256px';  // added this line
        this.cache[key].src = this.getTileUrl(coord, zoom);
        this.cache[key].setAttribute('gTileKey', key);
        this.cache[key].onerror = function() { img.style.display = 'none'; };
    }
    return this.cache[key];
};
```